# Live audio streaming from web and shoutcast

Tags: audio-streaming, webrtc, shoutcast

I want to record audio through the web browser using mic and want to stream that to my shoutcast server. So that user can listen the live streaming instantly. Is there any possible way to do this. Will be playable from iPhone as well.

Had search a lot of things over the web but can't find the exact one. Please let me know if there any possible way.

Already used the WebRTC audio broadcasting [script](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/audio-broadcast). Which is working over the web but the stream is not available on iPhone. Whenever I am going to joint a room it displays can't play the audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this in the past.  You can try it out at http://demo.audiopump.co:3000.

The only way to current get audio in the browser is with getUserMedia and the Web Audio API.  This gets you PCM samples.  Unfortunately there is no way to use the browser codecs programmatically currently.

I handle this by sending the PCM samples to the server.  Now, I don't send them as 32-bit floats, which is the format they are in.  I detect the buffer size for the web socket and adjust the bit depth accordingly.  If there is enough bandwidth I will send 16-bit stereo.  Otherwise I can drop down to 8-bit mono.  On the server, the samples are converted back up to 32-bit float and encoded with Ffmpeg.

From there, the data is sent live to the SHOUTcast server.

Comment: Thanks for the demo Brad, Exactly this is the technique I want to implement. But on your demo I have added my shoutcast server details 

Address: s4.myradiostream.com
Port: 8728
Pass: xxxxx
Codec: MP3 128Kbit

And from the settings option I have choosen

Bit-depth: 8 bit
Channels: Mono

But the streaming is not available on shoutcast's [player](http://myradiostream.com/objradio) page.

Can you please enlighten me how can I test that? Or what information I need to provide exactly. 

Also I have registered to your site using my Google account but it's giving me some error.

Comment: Hi Brad, can you please describe more about this demo, how I can use it ?

Comment: Did you document this technique anywhere by chance?

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. So far, I visualize this case as the "transcoding server" being a client in a quake style game. And the Person On Air being a player with insanely low latency. I follow what games do (although with a higher ease), The server always stays n seconds behind the client, which pumps mic stream and event input to the server. The server then mixes these two streams to play audio and pipe it to shoutcast. Any tips :-)?

Comment: @Abhishrek Since this wouldn't be web based, you have a whole host of options available to you.  I recommend posting a new question with more details about what you want to do, and then drop me a link to that question.  brad@musatcha.com

Comment: Oh no, what I am doing is web-based. Basically the transcoder/mixer/broadcaster is on server with the interface stays on the client allowing you to broadcast through pretty much anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Record audio using [RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC); use ffmpeg.js or ffmpeg-asm.js to convert WAV to mp3 or ogg; then you can make HTTP-PUT request to shoutcast server to upload low-size ogg; then shoutcast server can broadcast it to all relevant radio stations.

*P.S. By "low-size" I mean, for 1 minute audio; you can get 700kb to 1024kb ogg.*

*P.S. I'll add some demos on my github repository; very soon.*

---

**Updated:**

It is possible to use Google Speech Recognition API to convert voice to text; that text can be streamed to nodejs server through socketio; where you can use ffmpeg for text-to-speech and encode into ogg or other formats; that encoded ogg can be forwarded (using PUT request) to shoutcast server.

You can try [Translator.js](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/Translator.js).

Comment: There is another case where TURN can be used to record RTP/RTCP packets and relay over shoutcast. Media servers can also be used for forwarding recorded streams. I'm planning to try both but I'm afarid about PUT request limitation i.e. shoutcast/icecast accepts only PUT requests; hope I'll be able to make PUT from nodejs or from a real media server. WebRTC implementation in nodejs is promising however still work in progress. You can find a repo here: https://github.com/js-platform/node-webrtc

Comment: Ah, you were the person that wrote node-webrtc!  Awesome.  I've tried to get it working myself a few months ago but with no luck.  libjingle is part of another project now, and I couldn't get the pre-compiled binaries to run without segfault.  For my case, I wanted more control over the audio quality anyway, so I went with PCM.  Nice project though!

Comment: Nop. I didn't write node-webrtc. It is managed by: https://github.com/js-platform/node-webrtc/graphs/contributors

Comment: @Brad I wonder if you counted github-electron as a viable option, it can run headless and has the same webrtc implementation as chrome plus native stuff like node so you don't have to re-write everything in electron land. It makes it uniquely suitable for the scenario.

Comment: @Abhishrek I looked into it.  Electron doesn't truly run headless.  It uses xvfb as well.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, We can record the live Audio streaming using AVAudioSession . Please go through Apple document for further details.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: The question is asking about web-based solutions, not iOS.